# estoy tratando de hacer un metodo que agregue al fina de la lista simple pero no logro que agrege nada

Tags: java

en este codigo estoy tratando de agregar al final de una lista simple pero cuando realizo la prueba no agrega nadaa la lista

```
        public void adicionarAlFinal(E elemento){  
        NodoSimple<E> nodoNuevo = new NodoSimple<>(elemento); 
        if(estaVacia()) {
         //Caso Lista Vacia
             nodoInicial = nodoNuevo;
        }
        else{
            NodoSimple<E> nodoFinal = null;
          //Caso con al menos un elemento en la lista
          nodoNuevo.siguiente = nodoFinal; //nodoNuevo -> nodoFinal
          nodoFinal = nodoNuevo ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Ya depuraste el código para ver por qué está vacía?

Comment: lo que yo quiero saber es si el codigo esta correcto o me e equivocado en algo

Answer (score 0):

Veo un problema en `nodoFinal = nodoNuevo ;`

`nodoFinal` es una variable local del metodo,  y por el aspecto del metodo, creo que debería asignarse a una variable de la clase.

Saludos!

Comment: nodo final es una variable local

Comment: ¿ Puedes compartir la clase entera ?

Comment: intenté pegar el codigo y no me permite

Comment: public class ListaSimple<E> implements Lista<E>, Serializable {
protected NodoSimple<E> nodoInicial;
    @Override
    public void adicionarAlInicio(E elemento) {
        NodoSimple<E> nodoNuevo = new NodoSimple<>(elemento);
        if (estaVacia()) {
            //Caso Lista Vacia
            nodoInicial = nodoNuevo;
        } else {
            //Caso con al menos un elemento en la lista            
            nodoNuevo.siguiente = nodoInicial; //nodoNuevo -> nodoInicial
            nodoInicial = nodoNuevo;

Comment: Pues lo que te decia, deberías tener un protected NodoSimple<E> nodoFinal; y usar ese en lugar del que creas en el else.